# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server] SQLSTATE: 42000, CODE: 3980

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

What is the possible problem with my API service, when I executing a insert query into the SQL Server database using Zf2's TableGateway it always showing with an error:

> SQLSTATE: 42000
>
> Code: 3980
>
> Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The request failed to run because the batch is aborted, this can be caused by abort signal sent from client, or another request is running in the same session, which makes the session busy.

Here is my example of my code:

```
<?php
namespace Unilever\V1\Rest\RouteDetailSku;

use ZF\ApiProblem\ApiProblem;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;;

class RouteDetailSkuMapper {
    protected $adapter;
    protected $table;
    function __construct($adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->table = new TableGateway("route_detail_order", $this->adapter);
    }

    function save($data) {

        try{
           $this->table->insert((array) $data);
           $generatedData['data']  = $this->table->select((array) $data)->current();
            return new ApiProblem(201, "Success", "Route Detail SKU", "Create Route Detail SKU", (array) $generatedData);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } catch(\RuntimeException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

This only showing on the INSERT but when doing the select query it is okay. How I can solve this?

Comment: Is there more to the error message, such as `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`? Possibly the client connection is timing out before the insert operation completes. Do you have resource-intensive insert trigger on the route_detail_order table, or one that somehow blocks or recurses on itself?

Comment: This is the only error message it is returning. I tried to bypass it by setting the value of the timeout of execution to 1 minute through PHP but still returning same error.

Comment: I am not familiar with that DB, but could it be that you have some kind of buffered result set from previous query that was not fully consumed and there is still open cursor, similar to mysql buffered results?

Comment: Does he do the INSERT? Did you debug the insert() statement? Maybe the data array is not correct? The select() with the $data array doesn’t look right to me. Is it for debug only? Are you sure you have the right to do INSERTs (db_datawriter)?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I already solved this problem. This error was causing by one of my trigger related on that table so I just removed that trigger then the error has  been resolved again thanks for the answering guys.